# Probability of painting the whole wall with bars of 1x10 pixel length

Tags: probability, puzzle

Today I faced an interesting question. Let me tell the full story, my colleauge was in an muesum and saw a specific art. The painter was writing words on a wall until the wall was nearly filled up to 100% with red paint. It was not live, but you saw the red wall and a cinematic how the painter was working.
So he asked me, how many words you have to write until the wall is filled to 100%. Since this can't be solved in a correct matter, we abstracted it.

We have a wall of 50 x 10 Pixels in size. One word consists of 10x1 Pixels and you can write them from top to bottom or left to right or even diagonal.
As shown below.

You can start your word or line from any point of the map, so there are 500 starting points. It's also allowed to cross the border and finish the word on the opposite.

So for the first word you have 500 pixels to start and you will for sure not touch any other pixel, since there are none. so you will take 1/50 of the space. The second word has may touch some or even all of your pixels (in case its the identical line). so 10/500 is already black.
To me its like drawing a balls out of an urne... if you pick 10 balls out of 500 where 490 are white and 10 are black you still have a good chance of picking only white ones :) 490/500 equals 98% for the first pick. which leaves us 10/499 spots left, since I wont hit my first pixel again ...

There must be some better formula behind all this, can you guys/girls help me out? While I try to do it on my own here :)?

[image]

Comment: You question is unclear as to whether the rectangle is $10 \times 50$ or $100 \times 50$ - I'll assume the former. Possibly similar to a coupon-collector's problem with $10$ distinct coupons in each packet.  So the expected number of words may be slightly less than $\frac{500}{10}H_{500}$

Comment: It's not really like piking balls from an urn, because the $10$ pixels have to be contiguous.

Comment: @Henry Do you mean $5000?$ The wall is $100\times50$ pixels.

Comment: @saulspatz - the question is inconsistent about whether there are $500$ or $5000$ pixels

Comment: I corrected it, excuse me. The drawing is correct

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but there's no way to fit it in a hint.  I wrote a python script to simulate the experiment:

```
from random import randint,seed

def color(direction, x, y):
    if direction == 0:
        return { (a%width,y) for a in range(x,x+10) }
    if direction == 1:
        return { (x,a%height) for a in range(y,y+10) }
    if direction == 2:
        return {((x+a)%width, (y+a)%height) for a in range(10)}
    if direction == 3:
        return {((x-a)%width, (y-a)%height) for a in range(10)}

width = 50
height = 10
trials = 1000
average = 0

seed()

for _ in range(trials):
    count = 0
    pixels = set()
    while len(pixels)<width*height:
        direction = randint(0, 3)
        x = randint(0,49)
        y = randint(0,9)
        pixels |= color(direction,x,y)
        count += 1
    average += count
print(average/trials)
```

I've run it several times, and it's always produced answers in the range $(330,340).$  This is considerably smaller than $4\cdot50H_{50}\approx900,$ which I knew was an overestimate, but it's also a lot smaller than I can come to grips with.  The expected number of words needed to cover a particular pixel is $50$.  So at the end, if we have a couple of uncolored pixels left, that can't be covered by the same word, it takes 100 words, on average, to color both of them.  I would expect it to take much longer than $340$ words to color all the pixels.

Comment: $\frac{500}{10}H_{500} \approx 339.64$ so something slightly less than this looks plausible to me

Comment: @Henry Yes, that looks very good.  On the other hand, I tried this for a $20\times50-$pixel wall, still using $10-$pixel words, and got results in the range $(1100,1130).$ Now, $100H_{1000}\approx748.547,$ so some adjustment is needed.

Comment: @saulspatz: Made my own simulation and get similar results for $10 \times 50$, but for $20 \times 50$ I get numbers in the range $(735, 745)$.

Comment: @Jens Oops.  I'll check and report back.

Comment: @Jens I agree with you.  When will I learn **never** to type magic numbers in a script?

Comment: @Henry Your suggestion is looking very good.  Have you any idea about how to approach a proof?

Comment: Sadly not - though for the coupon-collector's problem with $10$ distinct coupons in each packet then numerical calculation says $500$ coupons to collect would have an expected number of about $337.023$ packets, and $1000$ coupons to collect would have an expected number of about $745.622$ packets.  What I cannot do is extend this to the lines here